# Filling between two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I'm trying to create a figure using Tikz. A part of the figure looks like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Outer lining of the tube.
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (6.3,1.0) -- (6.3,-1.0) -- (8.3,-1.0) -- (8.3,-4.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (6.0,1.0) -- (6.0,-1.3) -- (8.0,-1.3) -- (8.0,-4.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (9.3,-4.0) -- (9.3,-1.0) -- (11.6,-1.0) -- (11.6,0.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (9.6,-4.0) -- (9.6,-1.3) -- (11.9,-1.3) -- (11.9,0.0)};

%Round bend which also needs to be filled with a color.
\def\arca {(8.3,-4.0) arc (180:0:0.5 and -0.5)}
\def\arcb {(8.0,-4.0) arc (180:0:0.8 and -0.8)}
\path [draw=black] \arca;
\path [draw=black] \arcb;

%Lines that are indicating a level. Space under these lines needs to be colored.
\draw (8.0,-2.5) -- (8.3,-2.5);
\draw [dashed] (8.3,-2.5) -- (10.3,-2.5);
\draw (9.3,-3.5) -- (9.6,-3.5);
\draw [dashed] (9.6,-3.5) -- (10.3,-3.5);
\draw [thick, <->] (10.2,-2.5) -- (10.2,-3.5);
\draw (10.6,-3.0) node {\begin{small}$\Delta P$\end{small}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is creating the following figure:
[image: Tube without coloring]

Now I want to fill the space under the lines that are indicating the level (the lines marked by the $\Delta P$). So in the end it should look something like this (only nicely filled, not as sloppy as in the this picture).
[image: Tube with Coloring under the level lines]

I have read a lot of examples of other (similar) questions, but I am still not able of figuring out how to do this.
Does someone have a simple solution to this (I am not very well trained with Latex or Tikz as you can probably see).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Just recreate the path for the filled area and use either \path[fill=black] or \fill[black].

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the replay. How do I recreate a path for the area that needs to be filled such that I can fill it? I can draw lines for the filled area in a way like I have done so far, but that leaves with the same problem. How do I integrate the \path[black] such that Latex knows what to fill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can create a path from the arcs you already defined for filling. I just slightly redefined your `arca` :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Outer lining of the tube.
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (6.3,1.0) -- (6.3,-1.0) -- (8.3,-1.0) -- (8.3,-4.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (6.0,1.0) -- (6.0,-1.3) -- (8.0,-1.3) -- (8.0,-4.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (9.3,-4.0) -- (9.3,-1.0) -- (11.6,-1.0) -- (11.6,0.0)};
\draw {[rounded corners=0.2cm] (9.6,-4.0) -- (9.6,-1.3) -- (11.9,-1.3) -- (11.9,0.0)};

%Round bend which also needs to be filled with a color.
\def\arca {(9.3,-4.0) arc (180:0:-0.5 and -0.5)}
\def\arcb {(8.0,-4.0) arc (180:0:0.8 and -0.8)}
% constructing, drawing and filling path
\path[draw,fill=red] (8,-2.5) -- (8,-4) -- \arcb -- (9.6,-4) -- (9.6,-3.5) -- (9.3,-3.5) -- (9.3,-4)  -- \arca  -- (8.3,-4) -- (8.3,-2.5) -- cycle;

%Lines that are indicating a level. Space under these lines needs to be colored.
\draw [dashed] (8.3,-2.5) -- (10.3,-2.5);
\draw [dashed] (9.6,-3.5) -- (10.3,-3.5);
\draw [thick, <->] (10.2,-2.5) -- (10.2,-3.5);
\draw (10.6,-3.0) node {\begin{small}$\Delta P$\end{small}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seriously, it is just this simple. Thanks for answering my question! It worked. I guess the 'cycle' part makes a closed loop?

Comment: Your completely right. It closes the path.

Comment: Just for completeness: Instead of `\path[draw,fill=red]` you could also just say `\filldraw[fill=red]`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `double` lines. `double distance` defines pipe width and `double=...` filling color which by default is white. This means that over a non white background the pipe is not transparent.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pipe/.style={draw, double, double distance=3mm, rounded corners=2mm},
    pipefull/.style={pipe, double=red}]

%Outer lining of the tube.
\draw[pipe] (6,1) |- ++(2,-2) -- ++(0,-3) coordinate (aux1) arc(-180:-0:0.6) coordinate (aux2) |-++(2,3)--++(0,2);

\draw[pipefull] ([yshift=2cm]aux1) coordinate(top) -- (aux1) arc(-180:-0:0.6) -- ([yshift=1cm]aux2) coordinate(bottom) ;

\draw[dashed] (top)--++(0:20mm) coordinate (aux3);
\draw[dashed] (bottom) -- (aux3|-bottom) coordinate (aux4);
\draw[<->,thick] ([xshift=-2mm]aux3)-- node[right, font=\small]{$\Delta P$} ([xshift=-2mm]aux4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]